# How to extract lines from a text file with a step?

Tags: linux, shell

I need to extract some selected lines from a high text file. The data looks something like this:

```
Generated by trjconv : P/L=1/400 t=   0.00000
11214
    1P1     aP1    1  80.48  35.36   4.25
    2P1     aP1    2  37.45   3.92   3.96
    3P2     aP2    3  18.53  -9.69   4.68
    4P2     aP2    4  55.39  74.34   4.60
Generated by trjconv : P/L=2/400 t=   0.00000
11214
    1P1     aP1    1  80.48  35.36   4.25
    2P1     aP1    2  37.45   3.92   3.96
    3P2     aP2    3  18.53  -9.69   4.68
    4P2     aP2    4  55.39  74.34   4.60
Generated by trjconv : P/L=3/400 t=   0.00000
11214
    1P1     aP1    1  80.48  35.36   4.25
    2P1     aP1    2  37.45   3.92   3.96
    3P2     aP2    3  18.53  -9.69   4.68
    4P2     aP2    4  55.39  74.34   4.60
```

I want to extract starting with 3rd line then 9th line and end with 15th line. It will looks something like this:

```
    1P1     aP1    1  80.48  35.36   4.25
    1P1     aP1    1  80.48  35.36   4.25
    1P1     aP1    1  80.48  35.36   4.25
```

Are there any ways to do that using awk, sed or any other command?

Comment: There are ways with awk, _and_ with sed, _and_ with nothing but bash builtins. So... err... _yes_?

Comment: `grep 1P1 YourFile` maybe?

Comment: Is there a specific rule you want to be followed to decide which lines to extract, or is it just the specific list of ranges and hardcoded numbers?

Comment: (with awk, one approach is to write an expression that tests `NR`; `awk 'NR == 1'` prints only the first line; `awk 'NR >= 3 && NR < 9'` for example will extract the region between the 3rd and 9th lines; etc).

Comment: I just want lines with specific intervals let's say I have lines 1-100 I want lines starting with 9, 18, 27.. so on till 100.

Comment: So `awk 'NR % 9 == 0'`, then? But what do you mean by the words "starting with"?

Comment: gnu sed lets you write `sed -n '3~6p'`

Comment: @WilliamPursell this command throws a error **sed: 1: '3~6p': invalid command code ~**

Comment: @Rohit  Yes, that will only work with gnu sed.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy awk works for small data set but I have big data with lines around 1 million lines and I want 5 lines then file has around 11214 lines to skip and get 11215th line and so on.. But your method prints line starting with line number 11212. I don't know why?

Comment: @Rohit, please provide something I can test myself to see the problem you're describing. `awk 'NR % 9 == 0'` prints every 9th line no matter how many there are. You can test this with `seq 1 1000000 | awk 'NR % 9 == 0' | tail` -- it only prints numbers evenly divisible by 9.

Comment: @Rohit, ...frankly, the easy suspicion is that there's something in your file that's throwing off the count -- a record with more or fewer lines than you expect.

Comment: Or if it's just the `"1P1"` lines you want `awk '$1 == "1P1"' file` will do. Otherwise, use the `NR % no` approach.

Comment: `awk '!((NR - 3) % 6)' < input > output`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I happen to use the sed command

```sh
sed -n '1~2p' filename > output_file
```